# Best practices for working around the lack of dynamically sized memory arrays in solidity

Tags: solidity, arrays, memory

Consider the following solidity function:

```
function example(uint256[] calldata _numbers) external {
    uint256[] memory _evenNumbers;

    // initialize `_evenNumbers` and populate it with even numbers from the `_numbers` array

    someOtherFunction(_evenNumbers);
}
```

`_numbers` is a `uint256` array containing an unspecified amount of even and odd numbers. `someOtherFunction` expects an array of even numbers, what's the best way to initialize and populate `_evenNumbers` with all even numbers from the `_numbers` array?

The simplest solution would be something like this:

```
function example(uint256[] calldata _numbers) external {
    uint256[] memory _evenNumbers = new uint256[](_numbers.length);

    // initialize _evenNumbers and populate it with even numbers from the _numbers array
    uint256 _evenCounter;
    for (uint256 i; i < _numbers.length; ++i) {
        if (_numbers[i] % 2 == 0) {
            _evenNumbers[_evenCounter] = _numbers[i];
            ++_evenCounter;
        }
    }

    someOtherFunction(_evenNumbers);
}
```

This unfortunately doesn't work as `_evenNumbers` would contain as many trailing zeros as the amount of odd numbers in the original `_numbers` array, which would be considered valid even numbers.

A way around that would be the following inline assembly code:

```
assembly {
    mstore(_evenNumbers, _evenCounter)
}
```

This works and is probably the most gas efficient way to do it but I don't think that using inline assembly can be considered a best practice, but the only other solution I can think of is count the even numbers with a `for` loop first and then populate `_evenNumbers` with a second `for` loop, which is very ugly and inefficient.

Answer (score 1):

I think the most gas-efficient way is moving the check condition into `someOtherFunction()` and processing the whole array.

Comment: My bad, I should've specified that this is just a very simple hypothetical and `someOtherFunction` is meant to be an external function we have no control over

Comment: I see. In this case, Array.slice(https://docs.soliditylang.org/en/v0.6.0/types.html#array-slices) should be the most efficient solidity method AFAIK.

Comment: Unfortunately array slices are only implemented for calldata arrays as of solidity 0.8.x